# MAX and SUM SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, sum, max

I want to display a highscore were the UserID only can be displayed once. And the TrixPoints are summed together were the highest score are on top, how do I do that?

I have three tables:

```
tblUser
*UserID
FirstName
LastName

tblTrix
*TrixID
TrixPoints
TrixName

tblUserTrix
*TrixID
*UserID
```

This is my SQL That dosent work as I want:

```
SELECT MAX(tblUser.UserID) AS UserID,
       MAX(tblUserTrix.TrixID) AS TrixID, 
       SUM(tblTrix.TrixPoints) AS TrixPoints
FROM tblUser INNER JOIN
     tblUserTrix ON tblUser.UserID = tblUserTrix.UserID INNER JOIN
     tblTrix ON tblUserTrix.TrixID = tblTrix.TrixID
WHERE tblUser.UserID = tblUserTrix.UserID
GROUP BY tblTrix.TrixPoints
ORDER BY tblTrix.TrixPoints
```

The problem is that I get alot of the same UserID. And the SUM dosent SUM all the TrixPoints together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ut.UserId, sum(t.TrixPoints) as TotalTrixPoints
from tblUserTrix ut
inner join tblUser u
on ut.UserId = u.UserId
left join tblTrix t
on ut.TrixId = t.TrixId
group by ut.UserId
order by TotalTrixPoints desc
```

What you are doing wrong in your query, first off you are grouping by the wrong field.  You don't want to group by points, as that will be how the db engine finds matches to aggregate for the result.  And your select functions are a bit off.  Try my solution and let me know if it gives you what you're looking for.

Also, your `ORDER BY` is using the default `asc`, but it looks like you want it in the opposite order, so you need to specify `desc`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: @MartinSmith good point, I have edited my query to kick that bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then this should work:

```
SELECT tblUser.UserID) AS UserID, SUM(TrixPoints) AS TrixPoints
FROM tblUser 
INNER JOIN tblUserTrix 
ON tblUser.UserID = tblUserTrix.UserID
INNER JOIN tblTrix 
ON tblUserTrix.TrixID = tblTrix.TrixID
GROUP BY tblUser.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tu.UserID, SUM(tt.TrixPoints) AS TotalTrixPoints
FROM tblUser tu
INNER JOIN tblUserTrix tut ON tu.UserID = tut.UserID
INNER JOIN tblTrix tt ON tut.TrixID = tt.TrixID
GROUP BY tu.UserID
ORDER BY TotalTrixPoints DESC
```